# Appending a row/column of different size to an array.

Tags: matlab

Recently, I came across this behaviour in `Matlab` and I am curious as to know why this happens.

```
a(1,:) = rand(4,1);
a(2,:) = rand(5,1);
```

This throws me `Subscripted assignment dimension mismatch.` error whereas

```
a(1,:) = rand(4,1);
a(2,1:5) = rand(5,1);
```

adjusts the array to the max column size and appends zero to the shorter ones.

My question is: Why the former code snippet doesn't do what the latter does(which seems very logical to me)? I don't see any reason as to why the former code snippet should work the way it does. Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `a(2,:) = rand(5,1);`, you are attempting to assign a 5x1 vector to a 4x1 matrix column. Hence the error.

With `a(2,1:5) = rand(5,1);`, you are explicitly referencing a 5th row, which tells the Matlab engine to expand the matrix accordingly before attempting the assignment operation. Hence, this will succeed.

The way I see it, trying to put 5 values into a 4 row vector likely comes from an error in the code, so the user has to explicitly state that this is what he intends to do. Of course, I can only infer on the intent of Mathworks developers when they specifiy the behavior of their language.